# How to randomly separate particles from center of a curve guide?

Tags: particles

How can I **randomly separate particles from the center of a curve guide?** I dont won't them to stay close to the center of the curve.

To create something as a **guided volume of sand** and not a sort of flat cloth weaving along the scene. My particles came from the tangents of a plane, not from it's normal. What options do I have to tweak on the curve guide panel?

Thanks!